# Showing a Hidden QTableView Column

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be very simple, but the more I look into it I wonder if it's a Qt bug.

So, I have a `QTableView` that has columns that can be shown/hidden as the user likes. After I initialize the table, I call a custom `restoreColumns()` method that hides the columns (using `QTableView::hideColumn()`) that the user had hidden the last time the GUI was open.

The problem then comes when the user tries to show the columns that were hidden by the user the last time the GUI was ran. The appropriate signal/slot gets called and run through but for some reason the `QTableView` isn't updating to display the column.

What's weird is that any column that is already displayed (was not hidden by the user the last time the GUI was ran) has no problems with getting hidden/shown.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

---

Here's how I initialize the table...

```
m_tableModel = new mytablemodel();
m_tableView = new mytableview();
m_tableView->setItemDelegate(m_tableDelegate);
m_tableView->setModel(m_tableModel);
```

Meat of restoreColumns() method:

```
for (int i=0; i<horizontalHeader()->count(); i++) {
    // load size to restore previous width
    ...
    horizontalHeader()->resizeSection(i, width); // restore width

    // load previous column position
    ...
    // restore column order
    int currentVisualIndex = horizontalHeader()->visualIndex(i);

    if (currentVisualIndex != visualIndex) 
        horizontalHeader()->moveSection(currentVisualIndex, visualIndex);

    // load previous hidden/shown state
    ...
    if (columnHidden) {
        hideColumn(i);
    } else {
        showColumn(i);
    }
}
```

Below is some sample code to show/hide one of the columns.

```
void mytableview::showAColumn(bool checked) {
    // mytableview is a subclass of qtableview
    if (checked)
        showColumn(COLUMN_A); // COLUMN_A is an enum for the column
    else
        hideColumn(COLUMN_A);
}
```

Which is connected to a `QAction` that can be accessed from the Menu and Context Menu of the `QHeaderView` of the `QTableView`.

```
connect(action, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(showAColumn(bool)));
```

Comment: Could you try adding a [`resizeColumnToContents`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#resizeColumnToContents) call after the `showColumn()`? (I'm thinking it the `hide` happens too early, the column might have an invalid size)

Comment: Tried it - no change. I think it has something to do with how the hideColumn comes before the tableview is painted onto the screen... not really sure how I'd go about calling my restoreColumns() method after the tableview's been drawn though.

Comment: I just added some more details to the restoreColumns() method. It seems like the stuff where I am resizing the column is where it gets messed up. When I commented out that section then it worked as expected. However, I then lost the ability to restore the previous column width...

Comment: I've finally figured out the offending code... It turns out when I'm loading the previous width of the hidden columns, the width that was saved was 0. 

So, when resizing the column make sure that the width is greater than 0. Do this and then the columns will show/hide as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are loading the previous width of the hidden columns, the width that was saved was 0. 

So, when resizing the column make sure that the width is greater than 0. 

Do this and then the columns will show/hide as expected.

Comment: This ought to be documented in the Qt `QTableView::hideColumn()` description.